# Comparing column alias results within a search

Tags: mysql

I have an query where I'm trying to locate a users within a specific radius of a zip code AND within a certain age range.  The specified range is also stored in the table.  Age is calculated in the query based on the birthdate field and is the column alias 'age' that I'm speaking of.  Doing my research I found that I can't use a column alias in a WHERE clause so I'm unsure how to do the age comparison.  Here is the query I have so far, any guidance on how I can compare 'age' to 'wantminage' and 'wantmaxage'?

```
SELECT
zipcodes.zip, zipcodes.city, zipcodes.state,
users.*, YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(users.birthdate) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(users.birthdate, 5)) as age, center.seekingdistance,
   (3959 * acos(cos(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                cos(radians(center.latitude)) *
                cos(radians(zipcodes.longitude ) -
                    radians(center.longitude)) +
                sin(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) *
                sin(radians(center.latitude)))) AS distance FROM
 ( ( SELECT users.username,
         users.zip,
         users.seekingdistance, users.seekingminage as wantminage, users.seekingmaxage as wantmaxage, 
         zipcodes.latitude,
         zipcodes.longitude FROM
  (users JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip)
  WHERE (username='tester55')
) center, zipcodes) INNER JOIN users ON zipcodes.zip = users.zip
WHERE (users.username <> 'tester55') 
HAVING (distance < center.seekingdistance)
ORDER BY distance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, you simply repeat the expressions that you used to derive the column in the result.  People commonly interpret this as duplicated effort, but it really isn't... during execution of a query, `WHERE` is logically processed *before* `SELECT`, not *after* -- the server's task is to identify the rows *where* we should then *select* and return col1, col2, col3... so `SELECT` is retrieving the value that `WHERE` used to identify the matching rows.  So duplicating the expressions is fine.

However... you need some additional direction down the correct path.  Much of the magic of relational databases is in the indexes, which allow the query optimizer to do what it is designed to do: identify the correct rows with the least amount of effort.   What you are doing, the way you are doing it, will not scale.  The server needs to evaluate these conditions and expressions for each row in the entire table, and that will slow you down to unacceptably poor performance as the number of rows increases.

A table can have multiple indexes, but when you are dealing with index-based optimizations, you generally must assume that only one index per query can be used. The optimizer selects one, based on heuristics. Multiple columns can be part of a single index, but whenever there is a range condition involved, only one range can be used.  The common illustration of this is a printed telephone directory.  It is a two column index (last_name, first_name).  If you know the last name, you can quickly find the desired first name, because those are sorted, too... but trying to find everyone with a specific first name is not possible -- the sorting of the first name is unhelpful if you don't know the last name.  Even if you know the last name starts with S (that's a range condition, last_name >= 'S' and last_name < 'T') it doesn't help you at all if you also want all the first names that start with J (a second range condition) among those whose last name starts with S.  You have no option but to scan through each S looking for all of the J.

Here... you have two ranges, age and distance.  Distance is particularly messy, so we'll cover age, first.

Date of birth is a good column to have, and to index, but we don't want to use functions and date math to derive an age and then find everyone within an age bracket.  Indexes don't work when the column is an argument to a function.  Instead, we want to resolve the desired age ranges into a range of birthdates.

```
WHERE users.birthdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL @max_age YEAR)
  AND users.birthdate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL @min_age YEAR)
```

Taking two static values, shown here as `@max_age` and `@min_age`, with an index on (birthdate) we have an optimal query, because the `DATE_SUB()`s resolve at the beginning of query planning into two constant values -- *a range condition* -- and we can go directly to exactly those rows via the index, and not even bother to check any other rows.  They won't even be examined, because the optimizer knows they are out of range, and uninteresting.

As for distance, that's far more complicated, but may give you a bigger advantage than age, if indexed properly.  What you need there is a spatial index.  MySQL uses an R-Tree for this, which organizes the lat/long into a two-dimensional index based on minimum bounding rectangles, providing an efficient structure for identifying two points within a certain  distance, though you will likely find it easier to match a someone coarser, larger box and then filtering out some outliers... but this can all be done in SQL, with a combination of your existing logic and spatial query functions -- when the optimizer finds its optimal query plan, it doesn't care that it isn't perfect.  In the last name S* first name J* scenario, the server would use the index to find S* and then scan through the matching rows discarding everything not matching J* -- it wouldn't typically dismiss the index as unhelpful simply because it doesn't provide the total solution.  It takes the best path it thinks it can find and does the rest of the work itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This helps and it worked.  I'm not a DBA so I'm still a little iffy on the indexing but I'm going to keep reading your advice and research until I understand.  Do I need to put an index on birthdate?

Comment: Happy to help.  Yes, `ALTER TABLE users ADD KEY (birthdate);`.  Also, see [Use the Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com).  It should be very helpful.  It has been around for several years, but is apparently still being kept up to date.  (Even if it hadn't, the principles have remained the same.)